# What is it called when in the statement "she recommended that I read a book", the phrase "a book" can refer to a specific book or any book?

Tags: grammar

If she recommended a specific book, then I could say that "She recommended that I read a book" where "a book" refers to a specific book. However, the same sentence could mean that she was recommending that I read any book. What is the phenomenon called?

Comment: It's called "English".  A language that revels in its ambiguity.

Comment: I think she is suggesting, not subtlety, that you require a bit more intelligence to comment on the current discussion. That she does not suggest a specific book is the clue. The phenomenon is called an insult to your intelligence.

Comment: @Elliot -  If I recommended to you to read “War and Peace”   You might say to your friend, “Jim recommended a book to me yesterday.”  This is what the OP is asking  about.

Comment: @Jim - If she had meant any specific book she would have provided a title. *War and Peace* was not provided and so she is suggesting by her generalization that the OP get himself an education. There is no phenomenon involved at all. Just an insult.

Comment: If it were a specific book, it would be ***the*** *book*. Unless the sentence was followed by another one that gave the title.

Comment: @Elliot -  Sorry, but I disagree with your analysis.  Emily is telling us that she recommended a specific book in the premise to the question.  Let’s suppose it was W&P.  Now Emily says to a friend, “Yes, she recommended a book to me.”   The friend could say, “Oh, which one?”  And Emily can reply, “War and Peace”

Comment: @JasonBassford -  Not in the scenario I have described  Which I’m pretty sure is what OP is asking about.

Comment: @Jim And I'm fairly certain that you have the wrong interpretation. Read the last part of the title of the question again. It's asking about **ambiguity** (or so-called conceptual polysemy). But that's only possible in the described scenario if more context than has been given is assumed.

Comment: @JasonBassford -  She’s asking because in her mind she knows it’s War and Peace (for example) but she’s saying “a”  book.  So it appears that while “a” usually refers to any book, in this statement she knows exactly which book she’s talking about even though it’s not explicitly mentioned in the sentence.   Consider the scenario I provided in the comment to Elliot.  “Jim recommended ***a*** book...”  it is intentionally vague on which book was recommended even though the speaker knows exactly which one it is.  If anything,the answer to OP’s question is “it’s called being intentionally vague.”

Comment: @Jim, I suppose I can see your point buried int he initial question but all examples stated are her saying "a book". Other variations are theoretical. Neither or our points has to do with the OP's question I think.